# Why I getting double email open events in google analytics?

Tags: email, google-analytics, html-email, event-tracking

I have a website where I want to track opening of my emails. I've added google analytics image like this:

```
<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXXXX-X&cid={{analyticsCID}}&t=event&ec=email_open&ea=come_back_3&ni=1"/>
```

And I'm getting double email open event on first open of the letter. If I open email on mobile, only 1 event fired.

Is there any solution for this? Is it because of google proxy for images? Can I disable it to get CORRECT analytics data?

Answer (score 1):

Likely because of email providers caching the image through a proxy: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email#gmail-image-proxy